# Does query_timeout abort the server-side query on timeout?

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I'm trying to debug a pymssql issue wrt long running SQL Server queries.

I've set timeout aka `query_timeout` on all connections, but I'm wondering if this would actually send a signal to kill the (server) query, or just end the client-side wait.

Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/khen1234/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-query-timeout it seems it might be possible to send a message to the server to cancel the query?

Comment: Client APIs send a cancel request to the server when a query times out. This appears as an attention event in a server-side trace.

Comment: If the client crashes, this could leave the server process continuing?

Comment: The OS and SQL Server should detect the abruptly terminated connection and SQL Server will rollback the transaction. Query execution will not continue but the rollback will occur on the session even without a connected client.